# Can't import custom modules in python3.9 when running in wsl2

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

So I am trying to write some python code that will do two things, that seem to be mutually exclusive on my machine. My PC's host operating system is windows and I run Kali-Linux in WSL2 when I need to test my code on Linux. My code's main function creates two separate multiprocessing.Process objects, assigning a different thread, starting them both one after the other and then calling for them both to be joined. The plan is to allow each to run a simple server application simultaneously on different ports. This does not work when running python3 in PowerShell, as it seems to require access to os.fork() which doesn't work in said environment. When I found this out I pivoted to running in WSL2 which worked fantastically, for a time. After a while of experimenting with some ideas I decided to take some of my code and spin it off into its own file, which I placed in its own 'Libs' folder. WSL2 however, was unable to import this new file, instead giving me the exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NetStuff'`. I originally had added:

```
sys.path.append('./Libs')
```

as has worked for me in the past, however when I found that WSL2 was unable to find my module, I printed out sys.path and it revealed that rather than appending my $current_working_directory/Libs like I intended, I was just appending the literal string, which wasn't useful. I then decided to try:

```
sys.path.append(str(pathlib.Path().resolve()) + '/Libs')
```

which at the bare minimum shows up as I would expect in sys.path. This, however still didn't work, python was unable to find my module and would unceremoniously crash every time. This led me to try something else, I ran my code in python3 under PowerShell again, which had no issue importing my module, it did still crash due to lacking os.fork() but the import gave no issues. Confused and annoyed I opened my code in IDLE 3.9 which, for some inexplicable reason, was able to import the file, and seemingly use os.fork(). The only major issue with running in IDLE is that it is seemingly incapable of understanding ascii colour escape characters. Given that the goal is to run my code in bash, and ideally also PowerShell, I am not satisfied with this as a solution. I returned to trying to fix the issue in WSL2 by adding my module to /home/Noah/bin, and appending this directory to sys.path, but this has still not so much as given me a new symptom.

I am utterly at a loss at this point. none of the fixes I know off hand are working, and neither are the new ones I've found online. I can't tell if I'm just missing something fundamental about python or if I'm running into a bug, if it's the latter, i can't seem to find other people with the same issue. As a result of my confusion and frustration I am appealing to you, kind users of stackoverflow.

The following is the snippet that is causing me problems in WSL2:

```
path0 = ('/home/Noah/bin')
path1 = (str(pathlib.Path().resolve()) + '/Libs')
sys.path.append(path0)
sys.path.append(path1)
print(sys.path)
import NetStuff
```

The following is output of print(sys.path) in WSL2:

```
['/mnt/c/Users/Noah/VSCodeRepos/Python/BlackPack', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/noah/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/home/Noah/bin', '/mnt/c/Users/Noah/VSCodeRepos/Python/BlackPack/Libs']
```

The following is the error being thrown by WSL2:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/mnt/c/Users/Noah/VSCodeRepos/Python/BlackPack/BlackPackServer.py", line 21, in <module>
      import NetStuff
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NetStuff'
```

I am specifically hoping to fix the issue with WSL2 at the moment as I am fairly certain that getting the code to run on PowerShell is merely going to require rewriting my code so that it doesn't rely on os.fork(). Thank you for reading my problem, and if I left out any information that you would like to see just tell me and I'll add it in an edit!

Edit: I instantly realized that I should specify that my host machine is running windows 10.